# Statically link Go program to /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Tags: go, chroot

I am trying to get my Go program to run as a single stand-alone binary in a `chroot` jail. When I run the program in a `chroot` jail, it immediately dies with this error message: `Killed: 9`. I am building with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
export CGO_ENABLED=0
go build -ldflags=-s -o ./dist/contained ./source/main.go
```

Using `otool -L ./dist/contained` to see if any libraries link to it confirms my suspicion:

```
./dist/contained:
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

My question is: **how do I get /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib and all of its dependencies to statically link to a Go program?** I seem to be following all of the instructions I have seen elsewhere for statically-linking, so I don't get why there are still dynamically-linked files.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac OS, but could you please run whatever tool that platform has for `nm` or `objdump` (found on other platforms) on the compiled binary to see which exactly symbols it wants to import from that lib? This might give you some clue.

Comment: From a cursory look [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31705) is what you're after: a past change to the Go runtime made it use `libSystem` for DNS resolution if `cgo` is disabled. IOW, if you do not disable `cgo` your binary gets linked with a set of some system libs and if you do disable it your binary gets linked with another system lib. See [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12524) for a background.

Comment: From all these threads, I gather that you basically have two options: 1) Make sure your binary runs with [`GODEBUG=netdns=go`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution) in its environment. 2) Make sure your chroot jail has the necessary libs available. Note that with (1) your binary is still linked with `libSystem` so it might fail to be properly loaded in the jail unless the lib is unavailable anyway. So this looks like (2) may be a path of the least resistance while maintaining the possibility to have as feature-rich resolver as possible.

Comment: As to why (2) might be the best bet, see [this](https://engineering.grab.com/dns-resolution-in-go-and-cgo) (you might skip right to the conclusions)—it's about Linux but the situation with the resolver there is similar.

Answer (score 2):

As of Go 1.12, you cannot, on macOS - see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17490 for details.